# Go through cell L and font red if cell value is 0 and insert relational formula

Tags: vba, insert, formula

So everything works but the vlookup part. The lookup value of the vlookup does not move with the cell rows. I am not sure how to go about making the "F&cell.number" move along with the rows.

```
Sub fontredd()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Dim rngL As range
        Dim cell As range

        Set rngL = range("L1", range("L65536").End(xlUp))
        For Each cell In rngL
            If cell.Value = "0" Then
                cell.EntireRow.Font.Color = vbRed
                cell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F&cell.number,[PickupCompaniesCommissions.xls]Sheet1!$U:$V,2,FALSE)"
            End If
        Next cell
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F" & cell.Row & ", [PickupCompaniesCommissions.xls]Sheet1!$U:$V,2,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Missed the opening `[`